# count 1s in a number's binary representation

Tags: shell, sh

I have figured out a way to calculate the number of set bits in a given number using a c program. Program as below:

```
    unsigned int countSetBits(unsigned int n) 
    { 
        unsigned int count = 0; 
        while (n)
        { 
            count += n & 1; 
            n >>= 1; 
        } 
        return count; 
     }
```

Now i am trying implement the same in shell script, but facing the problem in one of the line

```
    count=0
    var=128

    while [ $var -gt 0 ]    
    do
            count=$(count + $((var&1))) // throws command not found on console
            var=$((var >> 1))
    done
    echo $count
```

Here, trying to print number of set bits in a variable var(128) ( expecting an output 1 bcz 128(10000000) has only one bit set.) Looking forward for your help as i am new to shell script.

Comment: `$(count ....)` invokes a program named `count`. The whole `$(....)` expression will be substituted by the output of the `count` program.

Comment: In addition, `$((var&1))` is invalid in both POSIX shell and Bourne Shell. You either have to use something like `bc`, or switch to a shell supporting arithmetic evaluation, for example Ksh, Zsh or bash.

Comment: @user1934428 `$((expression))` syntax is a part of [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04), as well as `&` operator.

Comment: I should have checked it. I tried it on `ash`, which I believed was a shall implementing the standard, and it did not work there. Indeed, in `dash` it does work. However, the OP also tagged the question by _sh_, which refers according to SO to the old Unix V7 Bourne Shell. Hence, questions tagged with this should get answers working on Bourne and POSIC. Beat me, but I don't think this construct existed back then (old Unix times) already. Of course I don't know why the OP is interested in such old shells....

Comment: @user1934428 tag description says ***since** Unix Version 7*; sh is rather the standard than a specific shell; on most systems it's a link to bash, dash, ksh or mksh. And POSIX just documents widely implemented features/behaviors/practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count=$(count + $((var&1)))
```

You don't need to nest arithmetic expansions. And above line should look like:

```
count=$((count+(var&1)))
```

I'd write it this way though:

```
cnt=0 var=128
while [ "$var" -gt 0 ]; do
  : $((cnt+=var&1, var>>=1))
done
echo "$cnt"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot oguz ismail, could you suggest me some good materials to master these function related concepts wrt shell scripts.